# How to Install Nodejs 7.X on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: node.js, centos, centos7, yum

This is my CentOS Version

[image]

I've tried the [official guide](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/) to install nodejs 7.10

and this is the result

[image]
[image]

how can I install v7.10?

Answer (score 0):

I became a lot happier when I removed system nodejs and installed nvm: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Then you can do something as simple as (assuming you do not need changes to your .bashrc/.bash_profile/or other shell config file for nvm to work correctly on your setup):

```
nvm install v7.10.0 && nvm use v7.10.0 && nvm alias default v7.10.0
```